# Date conversion and integer truncation during import

Tags: mysql, import

I am doing some data file imports using:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'apa.txt'
INTO TABLE Test_Stock_Daily
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(symbol, date, open, high, low, close, volume);
```

The date in the file is formatted *mm/dd/yyyy*. I need it to be *yyyymmdd* in the database.

The volume field needs to be truncated by two places so 123456 becomes 1234.

What are the most SQL-centric ways of doing this?

#### Table definition

[image: my schema]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I settled on:

```
DELETE FROM Stock_Daily where symbol = 'APA';
LOAD DATA
    INFILE 'APA.TXT'
    INTO TABLE Stock_Daily
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    (@date, open, high, low, close, @volume)
    SET date = STR_TO_DATE(@date, '%m/%d/%Y'), symbol = 'APA', volume = @volume/100;

SELECT * FROM Stock_Daily WHERE symbol = 'APA' and date >= "2016-02-26";
```

Some sample data:

```
02/26/2016,39.0900,40.4800,38.4000,39.4700,5545700
02/29/2016,39.4900,39.5000,37.6900,38.2800,5330100
03/01/2016,38.4700,38.6800,36.2600,38.6200,5884600
03/02/2016,38.3300,42.0100,38.1600,41.9700,6606500
03/03/2016,41.7500,45.6000,41.7500,45.0900,10047600
03/04/2016,45.6300,48.9400,45.1600,48.0400,8779000
```

Some sample output:

```
APA 2016-02-26  39.0900 40.4800 38.4000 39.4700 55457
APA 2016-02-29  39.4900 39.5000 37.6900 38.2800 53301
APA 2016-03-01  38.4700 38.6800 36.2600 38.6200 58846
APA 2016-03-02  38.3300 42.0100 38.1600 41.9700 66065
APA 2016-03-03  41.7500 45.6000 41.7500 45.0900 100476
APA 2016-03-04  45.6300 48.9400 45.1600 48.0400 87790
```

It would be really nice if I could replace all those 'APA's with a variable, but I gather that I can't do that without using a stored procedure so I think that I'll wrap in up in a Python wrapper like so:

```
 python reloadData.py APA
```

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that this is a bit cleaner than [Vérace's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/130498/1192):

```
LOAD DATA
    INFILE 'apa.txt'
    INTO TABLE Test_Stock_Daily
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    (symbol, @date, open, high, low, close, volume)
    SET date = STR_TO_DATE(@date, '%m/%d/%y');
```

(And yes, `date` is a poor choice for a column name.)

Answer (score 1):

1st an important point:

Do **not** have a column called "date" - it's an SQL keyword, and it makes debugging confusing - call it Stock_date or similar.

From [here](https://jameshd.wordpress.com/2010/04/08/mysql-load-data-infile-examples/) (it's been a while since I've used MySQL's INFILE), I came up with the code below. If you'd care to post a few lines of real data, I can check against that. Note: the code is **untested**. It may require some (ahem...) massaging before functioning properly, but it should give you a good start.

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'apa.txt'
INTO TABLE Test_Stock_Daily
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(symbol, date, open, high, low, close, volume)
SET Stock_date = SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING('12/17/2015', 7, 4), '-', SUBSTRING('12/17/2015', 1, 2), '-', SUBSTRING('12/17/2015', 4,2)), SET Volume = SELECT SUBSTRING('12345566', 1, length('12345566') - 2)
```

For '12/17/2015' substitute the string Stock_date (without quotes). This SQL converts the string from mm/dd/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd

For '12345566'  substitute Volume (again, without quotes)

Comment: I HATE the fact that column is named date. I wish there were a way to change it. The table was designed long ago when that did not appear to be a problem and many programs use it now. We have another table created long ago with a column named signal which is preventing up from upgrading to MySQL 5.5. (SIGNAL became a key word in 5.5.)

Comment: Ah, if we could only rewrite the whole thing from scratch. We know so much more now. As for the code, very helpful, thanks. I was going to try another approach to the truncation 'INT(volume/100)' but I like your LENGTH() idea.